# How to write mysql Trigger function for pass some id to another table and update the current table column

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, database-normalization

I have Cell table and Region table.when I insert data into cell table(cell id,cell name and region id only )it is trigger and find the district id from  region table also update the value district id of cell table  .
belove is my Cell table and region table;

```
+---------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
| cell_id | cell_name | region_id | district_id |
+---------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
|  000001 | cell1     |         1 |             |
|  000006 | cell6     |         6 |             |
|  000005 | cell5     |         5 |             |
|  000004 | cell4     |         4 |             |
|  000003 | cell3     |         3 |             |
+---------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
```

This is my Region Table;

```
+----+--------------+-------------+
| id | region_name  | district_id |
+----+--------------+-------------+
|  1 | fort         |           2 |
|  2 | hatton       |           4 |
|  3 | nugegoda     |           2 |
|  4 | wattala      |           2 |
|  5 | Nawala       |           2 |
|  6 | Dickoya      |           4 |
|  7 | kottegallaTT |           3 |
|  8 | Mabola       |           2 |
+----+--------------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need to do this.

The district ID column in the cell table is redundant. If you're just going to copy it from the Region table, then don't: duplicated data like that goes against relational database principles. It will leave your data de-normalised. Think - if ever you change the Region table to alter which district the region belongs to (e.g. due to re-organisation of districts), you don't want to have to find and change all the cell rows for that region too - it's just a waste of time. The whole purpose of a foreign key relationship like the one you've got between cell and region is so that you don't have to copy region-related information to the cell level.

Instead, if you need to know which district a cell belongs to you just write a query which joins to the region table, and then you can include the district column.

e.g.

```
SELECT *
FROM
  cell
  INNER JOIN region
    ON cell.region_id = region.id
```

will get you all cells and include the district ID in the output

Comment: sir i want  pass region_id of cell table  to the region table and find the district id  and update the district_id of cell table  when insert new value into cell table

Comment: @Gnanaseelan I think maybe you didn't quite understand my answer? It's not necessary to do that task.You don't need that district_id column in your cell table. You can delete the column entirely. There is no need to copy data which is already available in the region table. As I said, whenever you need to know which district a cell is associated with, you can simply include the Region table in your query - as per my example above - and it will tell you that information. You don't need to copy it into the cell table as well.

Answer (score -1):

TRY THIS :

```
create trigger set_district_id
after insert
on cell_table
referencing new as NEW
ON EACH ROW
BEGIN
 a number;
 select district_id into a from region_table where 
 id=:NEW.region_id;
 update cell_table set district_id=a where region_id=:NEW.region_id;
END;
/
```